# How to paint over texture [Libgdx]

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have original image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qYW2.png

How I can to paint over this image, than to get the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3ij3.png

PS: this code not valid:

```
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batcher.begin();
    batcher.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    batcher.draw(texture, x, y, width, height);
    batcher.end();
}
```

Comment: What  are you exactly trying to do? This code should do that thing.

Comment: @Veljko, this code do just tint.

Comment: Yup, then you must use simple fragment shader. That overrides the texture pixel color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full valid code:

```
        String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 a_position;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 a_color;\n" +
                "attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "uniform mat4 u_projTrans;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "varying vec4 v_color;\n" +
                "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "    v_color = a_color;\n" +
                "    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;\n" +
                "    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;\n" +
                "}";

        String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n" +
                "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "#endif\n" +
                "\n" +
                "varying vec4 v_color;\n" +
                "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" +
                "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" +
                "uniform mat4 u_projTrans;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "       vec4 color = v_color * texture2D( u_texture, v_texCoords );\n" +
                "       if( color.a == 0.0 ) gl_FragColor = vec4( color.r, color.g, color.b, 0.0 );\n" +
                "       else gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );" +
                "}";

        ShaderProgram shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader,fragmentShader);

        public void render() {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            batch.begin();
            batch.setShader(shaderProgram);
            batch.draw(texture, x, y, width, height);
            batch.end();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fragment shader with the following logic:

```
if(alpha of the pixel is 1.0) then pixel=cyan
else pixel=white
```

this of course requires the space that surrounds the penguin to be transparent(have a=0)

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    vec4 color=v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    if(color.a==1.0)gl_FragColor=vec4(0.5,0.5,1,1);
    else gl_FragColor=vec(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
}
```

Comment: There's a large gray shadow in the linked picture though. It might be better to set the color to cyan if alpha is exactly 1, and set it to (0,0,0,0) otherwise. (Didn't check the alpha channel in the linked picture, so not sure).